# Why doesn't react-redux connect take Dumb Component as argument directly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

New comers to react-redux are easy to get confused by this statement.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DumbComponent);
```

The `connect` method returns a new method to have `DumbComponent` as argument.

I'm wondering why not just have the `DumbComponent` directly as argument to connect. Just Like this.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, DumbComponent);
```

That looks less intimidating to new comers.

Any reason in the actual API design?

Comment: `connect` can accept up to 3 arguments.

Comment: Actually it can take up to 4 different args.

Answer (score 7):

One reason for this API design, may be so you can use it as a ES6 decorator. Like this:

```
@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
class DumbComponent extends React.Component { 
  ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Having `connect` return a new function that accepts the component makes it fit nicely with other higher-order components. For example, if using react-router and recompose, you might have code like:

```
export compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  withRouter,
  withHandlers({
    // ...
  })
)(DumbComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Redux and React-Redux use a number of Functional Programming principles throughout their design.  That includes the use of currying in a few places.

In this example, there might be cases where you would want to apply the same set of `mapState` and `mapDispatch` functions to several different "plain" components.  Not sure if that's the primary use case that they were thinking of at the time, but the use of currying with `connect` allows you to easily create multiple connected components with those same inputs.

Comment: "the same set of mapState and mapDispatch functions to several different "plain" components" --- you would not need currying for that. It would be possible with no problems even with a 4 arguments `connect` implementation.